# Class binding a ternary and non-ternary attributes

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Let's say I have a tag that uses a ternary operator to add alignment to it:

```
<td
  :class="alignment ? ('u-' + alignment) : null"
>
```

This works as expected since I have my pre-defined alignment classes with the number that I need, now I would like to add a new attribute in this tag, let's say I want to add the class `u-bright` if the prop `isBright` is true:

```
<td
  :class="{'u-bright' : isBright}"
>
```

How to keep both conditions in the same tag? Something like:

```
/** Obviously this doesn't work */
<td
  :class="{
    alignment ? ('u-' + alignment) : null,
    'u-bright' : isBright
  }"
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the [array syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax) :

```
<td
  :class="[alignment ? ('u-' + alignment):'',  isBright?'u-bright':'']"
>
```